# Spring Session + REST and x-auth-token

Tags: spring-session

I am newbie using Spring Session.
My intend is to use Spring Session on REST API. I followed an example, however have some unclear points.
The flow I tried to make is:
1. Request to login, providing in the http header user and password.
As I've seen, the information about session saved to the Redis.
2. Request to any resource of REST API providing sessionID. It throws an exception saying, a full authentication should be given.
I thought that if I provide sessionID in the header it would be enough? But it's not so.
Is it possible to achieve the mentioned afore flow using Spring Session?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. See the REST Guide at http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/rest.html If you provide more details (like your configuration) it would make this easier to help you solve your specific problem

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's what I've seen. What I tried to do is to run curl with the following:`code`curl -v http://localhost:9090/ -H "x-auth-token spring:session:sessions:ba44ad30-c4d4-40e5-900b-bb1f607cdb43"`code` and got the error that full authorization required. But the session was in the Redis. Probably I missed somethig ...

Comment: The configuration is the same as in exsamples about REST.

Comment: Are you trying the sample application or are you trying out your own? When you make a request that creates a session, do you see the x-auth-token header? Do you see SESSION cookie? Do you see JSESSIONID cookie? What container and version are you using (i.e. Tomcat 7.0.63)

Comment: Yes, I was running the example however changed it using maven. I.e. built maven project, added dependencies. The problem was in the syntax. I should have write x-auth-token[:] + token, but wrote without [:]. Thanks! Great work!!!